# Kivy: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'

Tags: python, widget, kivy, attributeerror

I was testing out the ActionBar widget of Kivy, here is my program -

```
 from kivy.app import App
 from kivy.lang import Builder
 from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

 Builder.load_string('''
 <RootWidget>:
      ActionBar:
          pos_hint: {'top':1}
      ActionView:
          ActionButton:
              text: "Button"
''')


class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
     pass

class MainApp(App):
     def build(self):
         return RootWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     MainApp().run()
```

Nothing much going on here, I just added an ActionBar inside the BoxLayout.
Here is the [traceback](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11468078/) which I am getting on executing the program.

Comment: Probably RootWidget needs An `__init__` that calls it's super constructor.

Comment: @PaulRooney I just tried that, but it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: What if you return an instance of BoxLayout from your build method. Same error?

Comment: @PaulRooney You mean this - http://paste.ubuntu.com/11468542/ , I am getting the same error if I run that program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try sth like this:

```
 <RootWidget>:
      ActionBar:
          pos_hint: {'top':1}
          ActionPrevious:
          ActionView:
              ActionButton:
                  text: "Button"
```

in your case the ActionView is treated as a child of RootWidget , also notice the ActionPrevious .

Comment: I do confirm that if you do commene out the line 'ActionPrevious', you get the error 'widget.fbind('pos_hint', self._trigger_layout)
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fbind''

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example of the use of ActionBar:

actionbardemo.kv

```
ActionBarDemo:

    # Reference actionbardemo.py
    #: import main actionbardemo

        <ActionBarDemo>:
            orientation: "vertical"
            padding: 10
            spacing: 10
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: [0.22,0.22,0.22]
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                ActionBar:
                    pos_hint: {'top':1}
                    ActionView:
                        use_separator: True
                        ActionPrevious:
                        ActionOverflow:
                            ActionButton:
                                text: 'Menu 1'
                                on_press: root.menuOne()
                            ActionButton:
                                text: 'Menu 2'
                                on_press: root.menuTwo()
            BoxLayout:
            TextInput:
```

actionbardemo.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class ActionBarDemo(BoxLayout):
    def menuOne(menu):
        popup = Popup(title='Popup', content=Label(text='Menu one'), size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
        popup.open()

    def menuTwo(menu):
        popup = Popup(title='Popup', content=Label(text='Menu two'), size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
        popup.open()

class ActionBarDemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ActionBarDemo()

if __name__== '__main__':
    dbApp = ActionBarDemoApp()

    dbApp.run()
```

Result:

[image: Demo on an Android smartphone]